# Numpy reshape sub-list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

For some reason, numpy reports the shape of 1-dimensional numpy-arrays without the number of rows. A numpy array with 784 elements has the shape: `(784,)`.
This is a problem, because the library I use expect a correct shape property (e.g. `(784, 1)`).

If I just have a single array, I can do this:
`train_y = train_y.reshape((train_y.shape[0], 1)`
But is there a way to reshape sub-arrays without doing a for-loop?
I have an array with shape
 `(60000, 784)`, however, the sub-arrays have the shape `(784,)`and I would like them to be `(784,1)` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NumPy is an n-dimensional array library, not a matrix library. 1D arrays don't *have* rows.

If you want a view of an arbitrary array with an extra length-1 axis stuck on the end, you can do that:

```
train_y = train_y[..., np.newaxis]
# or
train_y = train_y.reshape(train_y.shape + (1,))
```

though it may be better to change how you're initially creating this `train_y` array.

This will generate an array with shape `(60000, 784, 1)`. Depending on your expectations, this might be exactly what you want, or you might consider it an abomination. In any case, `train_y[0]` will have shape `(784, 1)`.

Comment: It is created from a list: `train_y = np.asarray(train_y, np.uint8)`. How can I create it instead to get the desired properties? As for it being an abomination; maybe so, but this is an assertion made by the Theano library, not my code.

Comment: @tsorn: Depends on where the list is coming from. There isn't really a better way to take in that list than asarray-ing it and changing the shape, but if you can make changes further up the pipeline, there might be better options.